# angular 2 taking too much time to load on browser

Tags: angular

hello I have created angular 2 app after successfully compile when I run it to browser it is taking too much time to load when I have checked on networks it is requesting for 14 items and 8 mb downloaded , can someone tell me how to reduce time of it

Comment: Does your server gzip the files? Do you use aot compilation? Do you use the build-optimizer from angular/cli?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce Angular 2 file size for deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976664/reduce-angular-2-file-size-for-deployment)

Comment: and how to to that

Comment: after compile all js file size if become more then 700kb

Answer (score 1):

2 Things you can directly do:

When you will deploy your app, use:  **AOT**:

```
ng-build --prod --aot
```

This will be more optimized.

And next, you can do **LazyLoading**.

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#lazy-loading-modules-with-the-router

But without your code, it will be hard to help more.

Answer (score 0):

please check you project size and theme assets size it is also matters as u said 14 items and 8 mb downloaded means some js are being download on load project so it is taking time so first delete extra sutff from your project if you are using these just put only required, pages, images, js, etc which are used in your project