# Unable to customize ng-image-slider size

Tags: angular

I am trying to decrease my video image  size but unable to do that 
Below is the link which i am using 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgtecl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
and I am using this slider
https://github.com/sanjayV/ng-image-slider

Please help me 
Or suggest best video player for the Angular 4
Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: [I hope that this answer, to a similar question asked in the past, will benefit you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976664/reduce-angular-2-file-size-for-deployment)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is bit different than my requirement  please can you check above link

Comment: Please can body can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me

You can use the `imageSize`

```
<ng-image-slider #nav
    [images]="imageObject"       
    [imageSize]="{width: '10%', height: 130}"
>
</ng-image-slider>
```